# Angular 9 Reactive Date Of Birth Validation With Three Select Fields

Tags: angular, validation, select, input

I have three form controls that are tied to three "select" type inputs:

```
this.visitor = this.formBuilder.group({
 dateofbirthmonth: new FormControl(null, {validators: [Validators.required]})
 dateofbirthday: new FormControl(null, {validators: [Validators.required]})
 dateofbirthyear: new FormControl(null, {validators: [Validators.required]})
},{validators: [Validators.required]}),
```

I would like to display the following error when a user selects an option from one of the three date of birth "selects", and navigates away to another field on the form (or clicks out into the body). Meaning if they select "January" from the month drop-down then, click on the "day" select input, then the error would not show, if the user clicks into another input after filling in one of the three selects (like "firstname"), then the error would show.

```
<div class="formfielderror" *ngIf="">Date of Birth is a required field.</div>
```

I am leaning more towards a custom validation, and have played with document.activeElement combined with blur/focus, but haven't found any good solutions. I would think there is an easy solution I am missing. Also, not sure if nested formGroups can help here as well. Thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you just use a datepicker? You usually won't have to rely on blur and focus, reactive forms have dirty, touched, valid, ... properties

Comment: Date Pickers have their place in UX, I don't believe it's best for DOB fields, considering the wide-range of dates that would be entered. IMO Datepickers would be good for things like appointment scheduling that have "next available dates" etc. I also thought about text types with regex, but all options considered this is the option I think is best, but leaving me with the question about how to handle all three of these fields as one. I have used  ".required" and ".dirty" with all other form fields in my ngIf, these all work as intended, but stuck with this LAST form field before I am done.

Comment: @NewDeveloper, There was an error in the stackblitz to show the "div dirty". In the condition the code is `*ngIf="form.get('prop1').dirty` (before it was writte form.get('prop1').touched). Just corrected

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can "play" with [dirty](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#dirty)

```
<div *ngIf="visitor.errors &&
visitor.get('dateofbirthmonth').dirty &&
visitor.get('dateofbirthday').dirty &&  
visitor.get('dateofbirthyear').dirty>error</div>
```

This div only show it when the three inputs are changed. But you want that if you select another else input the error is showed. To check if you "click" in another input or outside is a bit complex.

First we enclosed in a div and use a tempalte reference (in the e.g. 'zone') the three controls, when focus we are call to a function

```
<form  [formGroup]="visitor">
  <div #zone>
    <select  formControlName="dateofbirthmonth" (focus)="checkOutSide()">
      ...
    </select>
    <select formControlName="dateofbirthday" (focus)="checkOutSide()">
      ...
    </select>
    <select formControlName="dateofbirthyear" (focus)="checkOutSide()">
      ....
    </select>
  </div>
  <input formControlName="prop4">
  ..others inputs...
</form>
```

We has a viewChild to the div and a variable to store the subscribcion to fromEvent

```
  outSide$:any
  @ViewChild("zone") zone: ElementRef;
```

Out function, if the subscribcion is not do it, check a click and if clickTarget is in the zone or not

You can mark as dirty the controls using fromEvent 'rxjs' operator to mark as dirty. We make a function

```
  checkOutSide() {
    if (!this.outSide$) {
      this.outSide$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, "click")
        .pipe(
          filter(event => {
            const clickTarget = event.target as HTMLElement;
            return !this.zone.nativeElement.contains(clickTarget);
          }),
          take(1)
        )
        .subscribe(() => {
          ['dateofbirthmonth','dateofbirthday','dateofbirthyear'].forEach(x => {
            this.visitor.get(x).markAsDirty();
          });
          this.outSide$ = null;
        });
    }
  }
```

See a [fool stackblitz(*)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pnr2cq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

(*)I make a fool fromGroup with prop1,prop2,prop3 and show when is dirty the controls

Comment: This is closer to what I am looking to accomplish, but there are two issues with this solution. If I were to start with the third or second drop-down first, then click on the text-input (prop4), the error doesn't display. This appears to only work if you start with the first drop-down, then go to the second, then third. The other issue with this is the error appears after correctly filling out all three select fields properly.

Comment: to follow-up on this, I adjusted your solution a bit. I changed the ngIf to add a "form.invalid" and changed the "form.get('prop1').touched" to "form.get('prop1').dirty", I also adjusted the forEach loop inside the subscribe statement to look for values of the three formControls and if they have a value other than "null", set all three inputs to ".dirty". Seems to work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ::glups:: it's true, the *ngIf must be has form.get('prop1').dirty, I'm hapy you catch the error

Answer (score 0):

I went with a modified version of @Eliseo 's solution. Here is the final: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pz9xzn?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

The only things I am not smart enough to know at the moment is the performance related to this solution and all that comes with that.

The other thing I was a little concerned about was the ability to make sure those fields are required at time of form submission, but this was taken care of with the required Validator added to the formControls individually, so if they are not filled out at time of submission we can catch it with all the other form validators. Worked out pretty swell.